# Ao alterar uma opção do meu material select eu recebo: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>

Tags: react, material-ui

Possuo o seguinte componente de select do material-ui-react:

```
<FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
  <InputLabel ref={inputLabel} htmlFor="outlined-age-native-simple">
    Filial
  </InputLabel>
  <Select
    onChange={handleChange}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
    error={touched.filial && Boolean(errors.filial)}
    value={values.filial}
    defaultValue={'DEFAULT'}
    inputProps={{
      name: 'filial',
      id: 'outlined-filial-native-simple',
    }}
  >
    <option value="DEFAULT" disabled>Choose a salutation ...</option>
    <option value={10}>Ten</option>
    <option value={20}>Twenty</option>
    <option value={30}>Thirty</option>
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Quando eu altero o select eu recebo:

> index.js:1 Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on
>    instead of setting `selected` on

Estou utilizando o formik para tratar o formulário:

```
const enhanceWithFormik = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: () => ({ email: '', password: '', filial: '' }),
  handleSubmit: values => {
    console.log(values)
  },
  isInitialValid: false,
  validateOnChange: true,
  validateOnBlur: true,
  displayName: 'MyForm',
  validationSchema: schema
})
```

Quando eu preencho todos os campos e clico no botão de submit, é mostrado corretamente o valor que selecionei no select, porém estou recebendo esse erro.

Comment: Você pode enviar o código da function `handleChange`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Aos fatos

Para esclarecer, vamos entender o motivo de você estar recebendo esta mensagem antes de entrarmos no porquê.

Essa mensagem é dada pelo React e não pelo Material-UI. Precisamos entender é que o React sempre trabalha com componentes controlados ou não-controlados. Sendo componentes controlados o recomendado. Aqui segue uma [palhinha da documentação](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Quando o componente é controlado o estado que define a seleção é pela propriedade **value**. Assim sendo o React não espera que um elemento `<option>`, onde seu elemento **pai** é controlado, esteja marcado com o atributo **selected**.
Ou seja códigos assim irão cair nessa mensagem e o atributo **selected** será ignorado:

```
    <select onChange={handleChange} value={values.filial}>
      <option value="DEFAULT" disabled>Choose a salutation ...</option>
      <option selected value={10}>Ten</option>
      <option value={20}>Twenty</option>
      <option value={30}>Thirty</option>
    </select>

    <ul onChange={handleChange} value={values.filial}>
      <option value="DEFAULT" disabled>Choose a salutation ...</option>
      <option selected value={10}>Ten</option>
      <option value={20}>Twenty</option>
      <option value={30}>Thirty</option>
    </ul>
```

#### Mas então porque estou recebendo esta mensagem no `<Select>` do Material-UI se eu não estou colocando **selected** no elemento `<option>`?

O que esta ocorrendo é que o ***Select*** do Material-UI (reforçando, não é o elemento nativo `<select>`), quando controlado por uma propriedade **value** e não marcado com a propriedade **native**, espera que suas opções sejam elementos `<MenuItem>` e não `<option>`.

O Select do Material-UI irá renderizar as opções em um menu suspenso encaminhando a
a propriedade ***select*** para o elemento `<MenuItem>` que está selecionado([apenas indicando para aplicar estilos CSS de elemento selecionado](https://material-ui.com/api/list-item/#props)).

`<MenuItem selected value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>`

Renderizando então em:

`<li value={10}>Ten</li>`

Note que ao renderizar a propriedade **selected** não estará presente.
A renderização final com Material-UI ficará assim:

```
  <ul onChange={handleChange} value={values.filial}>
    <li value="DEFAULT" disabled>Choose a salutation ...</li>
    <li value={10}>Ten</li> //Renderiza com os estilos de CSS de um elemento selecionado
    <li value={20}>Twenty</li>
    <li value={30}>Thirty</li>
  </ul>
```

Note que o componente `<MenuItem>` é transformado em elemento `<li>` filho de um elemento `<ul>`.

Quando se utiliza o elemento `<option>` o Material-UI irá fazer o mesmo processo, porém ao identificar o item que está selecionado, ele irá encaminhar a mesma propriedade ***select*** para o elemento que colocarmos, nesse caso `<option>`.

`<option selected value={10}>Ten</option>`

No processo de renderização do React, ele irá detectar um elemento controlado marcado com ***selected***, caindo assim no cenário onde temos um elemento ***option*** com o atributo ***selected***, gerando a mensagem citada.

#### Então:

Ao usar o `Select` do Material-UI, sempre não sendo marcado com a propriedade **native**, use `<MenuItem>` para suas opções. Caso contrário pode utilizar normalmente o elemento `<option>`.

Outra dica com relação ao uso dos compontentes React, caso você use um componente controlado, evite o uso da propriedade ***defaultValue***, use o **value** para controlar, instanciando seu componente com a opção default no valor de ***value***.

`const [filial, setFilial] = React.useState("DEFAULT")`

Isso ajuda a evitar alguns warnings.